# Toggle button back change when another row click

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp

This is my form with toogle edit.

```html
<% while(resultset.next()){ %>
 <form method='POST' class="formfield" action='EditCompany'>
 <tbody>
 <tr align='center' class='form'>
 <td><%= no %><input type='hidden' class='form_id_data' name='form_id_data' value='<%= resultset.getString(1)%>'></td>
 <td><input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='<%= resultset.getString(2)%>' name='company_name'></td> 
 <td><input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='<%= resultset.getString(3)%>' name='city'></td> 
 <td><input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='<%= resultset.getString(4)%>' name='state'></td> 
 <td><input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='<%= resultset.getString(5)%>' name='zipcode'></td> 
 <td><input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='<%= resultset.getString(6)%>' name='branch'></td> 
 <td><input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='<%= resultset.getString(7)%>' name='address'></td>
 <td>
 <a class="edit"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>
    <input type='button' class='save' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-edit" value='Save'> 
    <a class="cancel"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a>
 <td><a href="#" data-href="DeleteCompany?id=<%= resultset.getString(1)%>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</form>
<% no++; } %>
```

This is the JS toogle, the button Edit, Save and Cencel.

```js
<!-- Toggle Edit -->
<script>
$('.edit').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.form').find('.aaa').attr('disabled',true);
 $(this).closest('tr').find('.aaa').attr('disabled',false);
    $(this).siblings('.save, .cancel').show();
});
</script>
<script>
$('.cancel').click(function() {
 $('.form').find('.aaa').attr('disabled',true);
    $(this).siblings('.edit').show();
    $(this).siblings('.save').hide();
    $(this).hide();
});
</script>

    <!-- Modal Edit Alert Script class Save-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $('.formfield').submit();
 });
    </script>
```

there is problem for toggle edit. when I click edit for first row show button 'Save' when I want to edit second row, button 'Save' in first row still showed. 
like this

[image]

> How to make the button save in first row back change to button change again.

Comment: the input tag does not close. maybe check your DOM in the browser if that may cause the issue

Comment: what do you mean? can you explain?

Comment: there is no </ input> for <input type='button' ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you.

**Code snippets:**

```
$('.edit').click(function () {
      $(this).hide(); 
      $(this).siblings('.edit').show();
      var trs = $(this).closest('tr').siblings();          
      $(trs).each(function () {
          //Check for the save and cancel button and hide them.
          var saveCancel = $(this).children().eq(7).find('.save, .cancel');
          if(saveCancel.length)
              saveCancel.hide();
      });                             
      $('.form').find('.aaa').attr('disabled', true);
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.aaa').attr('disabled', false);
      $(this).siblings('.save, .cancel').show();
  });
```

**UPDATE:**

[**FIDDLE SAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JbZnf/55/)

Updated Code Snippets:

```
$('.edit').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();//hide the edit button
    var trs = $(this).closest('tr').siblings(); //get the sibling TR elements of clicked row.
    //loop every TR elements
    $(trs).each(function () {
        var saveCancel = $(this).children().eq(7).find('.save, .cancel');//get the children of TR element that is TD. In which go to the 7th TD. Because that is the TD which holds edit, save and cancel buttons. From that TD find for save and cancel buttons.
        //Then check for the presence of save and cancel buttons.
        if (saveCancel.length && saveCancel.is(':visible')) {
            saveCancel.hide();//And then hide the both save and cancel buttons.
            $(saveCancel).siblings('.edit').show();//After hiding the save & cancel buttons, display their's edit button.
        }
    });        
    $('.form').find('.aaa').attr('disabled', true);
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.aaa').attr('disabled', false);
    $(this).siblings('.save, .cancel').show();
});
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: it doesn't work. the button edit dont want to back and button cencel not wroking

Comment: Try now. It will work. Or post fiddle with simple HTML and scripts alone.

Comment: wait, I wanna ask again, your sample is true but when I put into my apps its not work, I dont know why.

Comment: I predict, its about looping

Comment: Did you understand the logic of that code snippets?

Comment: I dont understand why you make tree table

Comment: I didn't make my own tree table. I just modified your HTML code based on your requirement. That's it.
Now check the comments in my updated answer to understand the logic of that code snippets.

Comment: but you repeat the form 3 times

Comment: Buddy I didn't repeat the form 3 times. Repeated the TR 3 times. That is for your understanding only.

Comment: and why must I do if I want do it into looping?

Comment: By looping only we can check other `tr`'s save & cancel buttons are hidden or displayed. If displayed means we can hide that.

Comment: I send my sourch code and helm me to fix it. I dont know what must I do